# Amazon SNS Unity - Cannot find GCMBroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I've gone through the readme on amazon for SNS and it's git repo.

Registering works fine and the mobile device creates an endpoint. Using the arn endpoint to publish a message the phone displays an app crashed message with the following stack trace:

```
03-01 19:53:34.781 17484 17484 E AndroidRuntime:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.company.appname.GCMBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.company.animamobile.GCMBroadcastReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.appname-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.appname-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.company.appname-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Assets/Plugins/Android contains all the relevant .jar files and i checked the amazon jar file if it contains the class using the `jar tf` cmd. Which it did.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.appname"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

  <permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.unity.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


  <application
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
      android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:debuggable="true">

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.company.appname.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.company.appname" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.company.appname.GCMIntentService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

[EDIT] Before posting, i decided to check further on SO. Found a post suggesting to add the google GCM.jar. Which i did and referenced in the AndroidManifest. App doesnt crash now so I had a look at the LogCat and got the following:

```
03-01 20:09:31.911  3582  3637 V BroadcastQueue: [background] Process cur broadcast BroadcastRecord{be5a3b5 u0 com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE qIdx=4}, state= (APP_RECEIVE) DELIVERED for app ProcessRecord{d9ba83e 20867:com.company.appname/u0a253}
03-01 20:09:31.921 20867 20867 V GCMBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE
03-01 20:09:31.921 20867 20867 V GCMBroadcastReceiver: GCM IntentService class: com.company.appname.GCMIntentService
03-01 20:09:31.921 20867 20867 V GCMBaseIntentService: Acquiring wakelock
03-01 20:09:31.921  3582  5879 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.company.appname cmp=com.company.appname/com.activate.gcm.GCMIntentService bqHint=4 (has extras) } U=0: not found
```

Comment: what version of Google play services are you building your app against? Also do NOT use the GCM.jar that has been deprecated and no longer supported, I dont even think you will get push notifications anymore with that

Comment: It's complaining about GCMIntentService being missing right now if i use the gcm.jar. I'm a bit puzled why it doesnt see the classes in the amazon jar. they are there. How do i check the google play services version?

Comment: look in your gradle file in android studio, what I am trying to get to is that GCMIntentService was removed in an update of google play services (I dont remember what version) and if Amazons SNS was not updated you need to target that version that has it

Comment: I'm using the Unity Amazon sdk from their dev portal. No gradle file is included. Google uses firebase, i was able to use the api server key to create an amazon application for sns so that seems to be compatible. Looking through the java classes they do include android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar.

I rolled back the gcm changes and set the path to both my app name and the java path (com.amazonaws.unity) but upon receiving the broadcast it cant find the BroadcastReceiver. Registering works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my android-support-v4.jar did not contain the WakefullBroadcastReceiver class.

I discovered this when going through the amazon java files and saw that it's BroadcastReceiver was extending this. Using jar tf on the android-suppotv4.jar revealed this class did not exist. I addd android-support-v13.jar to my project. Made sure my class paths were correct in the Manifest and the problem was resolved.